# Url redirection in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a link:

```
http://example.com/artists/david/?title=title-field
```

To something like this:

```
http://example.com/artists/david/title-field/
```

In my WordPress site. How can I do that?

Here 'david' and 'title-field' will change based on the page request

Comment: You can refer to this question 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14197/how-do-i-add-a-redirect-rule-to-wordpress

Comment: no problem WisdmLabs, i wanted to pass the value ?title=title-field  to another page. I done that using add_option(). Anyway thanks for your support